# Tensorflow library: flow_from_dataframe

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, conv-neural-network, linear-regression

I have done image augmentation and created the train set and validation set using the flow_from_dataframe function of tensorflow as shown below:

```
print("Creating a training set:")
train_set=img_aug.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=labels_df,
    directory='/kaggle/input/crowd-counting/frames/frames',
    x_col="image_name",
    y_col="count",
    target_size=img_size,
    shuffle=True,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode="raw",
    subset="training",
    )
print(np.array(train_set.filenames)[:10])
```

But I am getting the filenames in the sequential order:

```
Creating a training set:
Found 1600 validated image filenames.
['seq_000401.jpg' 'seq_000402.jpg' 'seq_000403.jpg' 'seq_000404.jpg'
 'seq_000405.jpg' 'seq_000406.jpg' 'seq_000407.jpg' 'seq_000408.jpg'
 'seq_000409.jpg' 'seq_000410.jpg']
```

I was expecting that if there is a folder full of image files by the names: 'seq*000401.jpg', 'seq*_000402.jpg', etc. and a data frame with an id of the image and count. If add another column for the filenames to be assigned as per the ID by using the code below:

```
print("Map each id to its appropriate file name:")
labels_df['image_name'] = labels_df['id'].map('seq_{:06d}.jpg'.format)
display(labels_df)
```

Creating a data frame like below:

```
    id  count   image_name
0   1   35  seq_000001.jpg
1   2   41  seq_000002.jpg
2   3   41  seq_000003.jpg
3   4   44  seq_000004.jpg
4   5   41  seq_000005.jpg
... ... ... ...
1995    1996    27  seq_001996.jpg
1996    1997    27  seq_001997.jpg
1997    1998    25  seq_001998.jpg
1998    1999    26  seq_001999.jpg
1999    2000    26  seq_002000.jpg
```

and then if I split the train and validation set using the code below:

```
print("Creating a training set:")
train_set=img_aug.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=labels_df,
    directory='/kaggle/input/crowd-counting/frames/frames',
    x_col="image_name",
    y_col="count",
    target_size=img_size,
    shuffle=True,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode="raw",
    subset="training",
    )
print(np.array(train_set.filenames)[:10])
```

```
print("Creating a validation set:")
validation_set=img_aug.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=labels_df,
    directory='/kaggle/input/crowd-counting/frames/frames',
    x_col="image_name",
    y_col="count",
    target_size=img_size,
    shuffle=True,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode="raw",
    subset="validation",
    )
print(np.array(validation_set.filenames)[:10])
```

I must get the filenames in random order and not sequential. After doing my training, I tested the r2 score to be coming as 0.88. I did the training using the code below:

```
model_path4="Crowd_Counting_Model4.h5"
checkpoint4=ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=model_path4,
    monitor='val_mean_squared_error',
    mode='min',
    save_best_only=True,
    verbose=1
)
print("Model Checkpoint Created:")
print(checkpoint4)
print()
print("Learning Rate Reduction:")
learning_rate_reduction4 = ReduceLROnPlateau(
    monitor='val_mean_squared_error',  
    patience=3,  
    verbose=1, 
    factor=0.2,  
    min_lr=0.000001
)
print(learning_rate_reduction4)
vgg16=VGG16(include_top=False,weights="imagenet",input_shape=(240,320,3),pooling="avg")
x = vgg16.output  
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)  
predictions = Dense(1, activation='linear')(x)
model4=Model(inputs=vgg16.input, outputs=predictions)
k = -7
for layer in model4.layers[:k]:
    layer.trainable = False
print('Trainable layers:')
for layer in model4.layers[k:]:
    print(layer.name)
    layer.trainable = True
print()
display(model4.summary())
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model4.compile(
    optimizer=optimizer, 
    loss="mean_squared_error", 
    metrics=['mean_absolute_error', 'mean_squared_error']
)
history4 = model4.fit_generator(
    generator=train_set,
    epochs=50, 
    validation_data=validation_set,
    verbose=2, 
    callbacks=[checkpoint4,learning_rate_reduction4],
)
print('\nModel Training Finished.')
```

But whenever I am uploading an image say "seq_000001.jpg", I am getting a prediction of 17 using the code below:

```
print("Enter the image name to predict:")
img_name="seq_000001.jpg"
img_path="/kaggle/input/crowd-counting/frames/frames/"+img_name
print(f"Image filepath: {img_path}")
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
img = cv2.imread(img_path)
img=img.astype(np.uint8)
plt.imshow(img)
test_img = cv2.resize(img, img_size)
print(f"Test image resized to {test_img.shape[:-1]}")
test_input = test_img.astype('float32') / 255.0
test_input = test_input.reshape((1, img_size[0], img_size[1], 3))
actual_count = labels_df[labels_df["image_name"] == img_name]["count"].values[0]
prediction = model.predict(test_input)[0, 0]
predicted_count = int(np.round(prediction))
plt.title(f"Actual people count: {actual_count}\n Predicted people count: {predicted_count}")
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```